# byte[] to audio in a ASP.NET MVC website

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, audio

I've been researching an upcoming project and would appreciate some Stack feedback. I need to create an intranet site that for our CSRs, for them to listen to daily customer recordings that are saved into our db (Cisco phone system inserts .wav files as byte[]). There's a dozen programs, each get a dozen calls recorded a day, each call having 5 or 6 short customer recordings (customers saying their first name, last name, etc..).

I was considering using this opportunity to build my first ASP.NET MVC. It was easy enough to create a site that accesses the db, but I cannot find any good examples of displaying audio in and MVC website. I thought about going down the Silverlight route, but the only way that is possible is if the files are PCM which I am not certain. So then I thought about using a file handler to retrieve the files and then just use an html 5 tag to display them (and tell the CSRs to update their damn browsers). It just has to play the messages for them, so there's no manipulation involved.

Any thoughts or examples come to mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like a simple enough approach.

Maybe something like this in your controller:

```
public ActionResult LoadAudio(int id) {
    var audioBytes = db.Messages.Where(w => w.Id == id).Single();
    return base.File(audioBytes, "audio/wav");
}
```

And in the view:

```
@foreach (var msg in Model.Messages) {
    <audio controls src="@Url.Action("LoadAudio", new { id = msg.Id })") />
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement this, but I'm having difficulty with the base.File return. I'm accessing the right byte[] with my linq statment, but it's not the right format for a File return it seems.

Comment: The base.File method takes a byte array. If you're using Linq 2 Sql or Entity Framework you're probably getting back a Binary object. You can just call .ToArray() on that object. If that doesn't work, debug and find out what type is being returned.

Comment: Figured it out afterall. For the sake of just seeing if it could work, I used the following to turn the var result into a byte[], and then it converted just fine. byte[] callaudio = call.ToArray().SingleOrDefault(); Of course this was just a direct download of the file, I now have to display it in the html 5 tag. But the hard part is over. Thanks